# Add custom text to routing direction waypoints marker

Tags: javascript, maps, markers, here-api

I'd like to add text to the waypoint markers in here maps, just like on their [site](http://here.com/directions), to be able to number the waypoints. It can get quite confusing if the route has over 20 waypoints.

This is my current routing code:

```
function drivingDirections(arr) {
    var waypointArray = new nokia.maps.routing.WaypointParameterList();

    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        waypointArray.addCoordinate(new nokia.maps.geo.Coordinate(arr[i][0], arr[i][2]));
    }

    var modes = [{
        type: "shortest",
        transportModes: ["car"],
        options: "avoidTollroad",
        trafficMode: "default"
    }];

    var onRouteCalculated = function (observedRouter, key, value) {
        if (value === "finished") {
            var routes = observedRouter.getRoutes();

            // Create the default map representation of a route
            var mapRoute = new nokia.maps.routing.component.RouteResultSet(routes[0]).container;
            map.objects.add(mapRoute);

            // Zoom to the bounding box of the route
            map.zoomTo(mapRoute.getBoundingBox(), false, "default");
        } else if (value === "failed") {
            alert("Sikertelen útvonaltervezés");
        }
    };

    router.addObserver("state", onRouteCalculated);
    router.calculateRoute(waypointArray, modes);
}
```

According to the documentation, this is how you can add text to a marker:

```
    var marker = new nokia.maps.map.StandardMarker([52.51, 13.4], {
        text: "Hi!"
    });
```

How can implement this in a routing request?

Right now it adds the default waypoint markers, which look like this: 
[image: default waypoint]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to alter the display of a route, you can't use the default `RouteResultSet`, you're going to have to implement your own logic for displaying the route `Polyline` and the waypoints. When you receive the route, just create a `Container` and throw the objects into it as you create them. You can alter the text and color of the `StandardMarkers` or replace them with custom `Markers` if you want. Something like this:

```
var legContainer = new nokia.maps.map.Container();
var onRouteCalculated = function (observedRouter, key, value) {
  if (value == "finished") {
    var firstroute = observedRouter.getRoutes()[0];
    // First clear any previous route.
    legContainer.objects.clear();    

    for (var i = 0;  i < firstroute.waypoints.length; i++){
        legContainer.objects.add(new nokia.maps.map.StandardMarker(
          firstroute.waypoints[i].mappedPosition, 
          { text: i  + 1 }
        ));
    }

    for (var i = 0;  i < firstroute.legs.length; i++){

      var strokeColor = "#22CA";

      if (i % 2 == 0){          
          strokeColor = "#CACA00"
      }

      legContainer.objects.add(new nokia.maps.map.Polyline(
          firstroute.legs[i].points,
          { 
            pen: {
              strokeColor: strokeColor, 
              lineWidth: 5
            }
          }
        ));
      } 
     map.objects.add(legContainer);
     map.zoomTo(legContainer.getBoundingBox(), true);
   } else if (value == "failed") {
      // Something has gone horribly wrong  e.g. route too long.
      alert("The routing request failed.");
  }
}
```

You can see an example of a custom route rendering [here](http://heremaps.github.io/examples/explorer.html#directions-rendering-component__draggable-a-to-b-with-directions) - it just sets the route polyline to a different color, but you should get the idea.

Assuming `legContainer` is given the correct scope, you can use `legContainer.objects.clear();`  to empty any `MapObjects` rendered previously.